# Byte setting an unsigned short

Tags: c++, memset

I'm trying to set the bytes in an unsigned short variable individually using `memset`:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  unsigned short test2; // 2 bytes

  std::cout << "size of test2: " << sizeof(test2) << std::endl;

  memset(&test2, 0, 2); 
  memset(&test2, 0x4D, 1);                                                               
  memset(&test2+1, 0x42, 1); 

  std::cout << "value: " << test2 << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

The output I'm getting is:

```
size of test2: 2
value: 77
```

77 is 0x4D. So for some reason it's not picking up the 0x42 that I'm trying to set on the second byte of the variable. Why is that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`&test2+1` will actually progress the address by `sizeof(test2)`, which is 2, and move the pointer to out-of-range.

Try this with casting to `char*`:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  unsigned short test2; // 2 bytes

  std::cout << "size of test2: " << sizeof(test2) << std::endl;

  memset(&test2, 0, 2); 
  memset(&test2, 0x4D, 1);                                                               
  memset((char*)&test2+1, 0x42, 1); 

  std::cout << "value: " << test2 << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I knew it was something fundamental I was missing. That totally makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

The expression `&test2+1` is scaled by the size of test, so you are setting the `unsigned short` that follows `test2` in memory, and not the top byte of `test2`. Since this `unsigned short` you are referencing is not allocated, you are invoking *undefined behaviour*.

You will have to cast `&test2` to `char *` to get a scaling of 1 (byte):

```
memset((char *)&test + 1, 0x42, 1);
```

Another way to do this without using `memset()`:

```
unsigned short setbytes(unsigned char hi, unsigned char lo)
{
    return hi << 8 | lo;
}

...    

    unsigned short test2 = setbytes(0x42, 0x4D); /* --> 0x424D */
```